# Click Event is Not Firing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My click Event is not Firing in backbone.js.I have search alot but my problem is not resolved.
following is the code:

```
EventView=Backbone.Model.extend({

   el:'modal_box',
events: {
    'click  #btn': 'insertText',
    'click .btndel': 'delme'
},


insertText: function (e) {
    alert('text inserted');
},
delme: function (e) {
    alert('text inserted');
}
```

});
**AND HTML IS**

```
<div class="modal_box">
<button id="btn"  >Add a Task </button>
<button class="btndel"  >delete all</button>
```

Comment: Have you loaded jquery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "el", you should supply a selector. Try:

```
el: '.modal_box',
...
```

Comment: Aditya R.  Not Working :(

Comment: Try the updated code. Also, you seem to have extra whitespace between 'click' and '#btn' in 'click  #btn'.

Comment: I remove whiteSpaces but Still NOT Working

Comment: EventView=Backbone.Model.extend is not correct. You're using a View, change it to EventView=Backbone.View.extend

Comment: That us My new Code But is not working
`EventView=Backbone.View.extend({

    el:'.modal_box',
    events: {
        'click #btn': 'insertText',
        'click .btndel': 'delme'
    },


    insertText: function (e) {
        alert('text inserted');
    },
    delme: function (e) {
        alert('text inserted');
    }


});`

Comment: Has your view been initialized?

e.g. var view = new EventView();

Comment: yeah i Initialize my view at the end of Code 
   `var init=new EventView `

Comment: I am getting this error in Google Console

**Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'off' **

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Backbone.js? I believe that an older version required that el had the method off().

Comment: Yeah i am using latest version But Now i will download the latest version of BB Again.
Thanks For Sharing your Precious Time With Me.